# Default Pointer Cursor CSS

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I mean to change my cursor pointer to a custom cursor.

I saw this topic but it wasn't of any help: "html, css - cursor - how to change default image for pointer".

Is there any way I can use CSS to resolve this issue, b/c I'm not allowed to use JavaScript on someone else's website where I am configuring my profile on. I can only use CSS Markup and HTML Markup.

There can't be a way to use JS in the CSS Markup, right?

Comment: Do you want to change the mouse pointer for everywhere on a page, or just when the mouse is over a specific element?

Comment: when the arrow cursor is over other elements, the pointer cursor pops in and I need that pointer cursor changed to a custom cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`.custom {
   cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}`

But I wouldn't recommend it due to browser incompatibilities. Credit to Chris Coyier / CSS-Tricks

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Comment: body, html { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 

background: #000 url('http://1hdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/undead_dragon.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;  

background-size:contain; 

cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), url('cute25.cur'), help; 

div#mask cursor: not-allowed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

Comment: I don't know how to make comments have code boxes, but where to I put your line into this?

Comment: Upon further testing I'd recommend using an svg inside of your body declaration in the CSS if you want the cursor over the whole page, like this:

`body {
  cursor: url(my_cursor.svg), auto;
}`

Comment: What do I replace (my_cursor.svg) with since this is the cursor I want: "http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png" ?

Comment: It's url is of the .png. The website is: "rw-designer.com/cursor-set/my-favorites", and in this website link is my account with a set of cursors which contains the one I want in the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution cross-browser which is suitable for Webkit(Chrome, Safari, etc), Gecko (Mozilla, etc) and IE8+ as well:

```
a.heroshot img {
    cursor:url(http://alienbill.com/kirkdev/magnify.cur), pointer;
    cursor:url(http://alienbill.com/kirkdev/magnify.cur), -moz-zoom-in;        
}
```

Check this **demo**:

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cbz9xkjv/

You should opt for using .cur files instead of images for replacing the cursor via CSS because .cur files are supported even from IE6. On the contrary if you use images you will have cross-browser issues.

Comment: a.heroshot img
        cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), pointer;
        cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), -moz-zoom-in; }

Comment: Can you tell me where I can get .cur urls and how to type code blocks for this post so I can post code that is easy to read for you?

Comment: I know about cursor editing, but I want to use someone else's .cur and the link to the one I want is the link to the png of that .cur.

Comment: You cannot put blocks of code inside comments but maximum you can add a backtick symbol ` and make words in `grey`